# PyQt QStandardItemModel - how to read a row as a list

Tags: python, pyqt, qstandarditemmodel

It seems easy to append a row by model.append(some_list) but there seems no easy equivalent like:

my_list = model.row(index)

where, for example, an index is acquired via a click or double-click on a list using the model.

Sorry if I am missing something obvious but have aread a lof stuuf before asking for help.

I have read the docs, some examples, an MVC tutorial and several forums.  What I would like is a simple bit of code that makes my life complete.

Comment: `rowItems = [model.item(row, c) for c in range(model.columnCount())]`.

Comment: Many thanks.  I knew there would be a Pythonic way of writing it but I am still learning and default to old-school loops.